# Rails - appending query parameters to existing URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application controller method called redirect back or default which is used to redirect users to the page they were requesting after login

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)      
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

I would like to be able to optionally add URL parameters (for some analytics tracking) to the url, but am not sure of the best way.  I'd like to change the method signature to this

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default, params=nil)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)      
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

and somehow attach the params to the existing URL.  Is there a standard ruby or ROR way to do this? I could obviously brute force check to see if there is a query string as part of the URL with regex and manually build the query string, but I was hoping there is an easier standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/98023):

> To pass parameters with redirect_to
>   you simply add them.  Like ...

```
 redirect_to :controller => 'another', :action => 'def', :param1 => 'some', :param2 => 'thing', :param => 'else'
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the URLs are already built at this point

Comment: I tried `redirect_to( (session[:return_to] || default), :test_param=>1 )`

Comment: Okay, so `session[:return_to]` and `default` contain complete URLs?

Comment: Right, because I'm saving the request uri that they were navigating to before hitting the page that requires a login.  Then after log in they get redirected to session[:return_to].

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't a built-in way to do what you want. [The documentation says](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) "String starting with protocol:// (like http://) - Is passed straight through as the target for redirection."

Comment: Also, http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/8da5c8d4593764bc

Answer (score 0):

standart approach

```
def redirect_to_back_or_default(default = "/")
  back = case request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
  when request.fullpath
    default
  when nil
    default
  else
    :back
  end
  redirect_to back
end
```

Comment: That still doesn't help me add an extra parameter to "back"